# Receive XML - PHP

Tags: php

I have send.php:

```
<?
 if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
  }
?>
```

And have receive.html:

```
 function makeRequestXML(url) {
            http_request = false;

            ...
            http_request.onreadystatechange = ContentsXML;
            http_request.open('GET', 'send.php', true);
            http_request.send(null);
        }
function ContentsXML() {
    alert(http_request.readyState);
    alert(http_request.status);
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                number_checkbox = 0;
                var xmldoc = http_request.responseXML;
```

but xmldoc's not XML.
I want to send XML($out).
How can I do it?

Comment: If you want to POST an XML document to a URI, take a look at the _Related_ items to the right of this question. You should find what you're looking for there. (Meanwhile it may be worth clarifying your question, as it is currently rather sparse on details!).

Comment: I know. Sorry. My English is not very well

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's unclear what `$out` contains, with PHP you can do some string operations to turn values into XML strings (in case that value can be turned into a string):

```
 printf('<root>%s</root>', htmlspecialchars($out));
```

Replace your `echo` line with that line and it probably already works. Otherwise you need to be more specifically what you ask about.